# Failure of Power Supply during Remote Desktop Connection makes the local Machine unusable?

Tags: power-management, rdp

With sudden failure of power supply in the remote machine makes the local machine desktop to a complete dead state, meaning I'm not able to kill the current remote desktop connection that was established from local machine. I believe the connection is no more, but the fullscreen mode prevents me to do any other task.

I used this command :

> rdesktop -u USERNAME -P PASSWORD -f
>
> ```
> -f forces it to render in fullscreen mode
> ```

Is there any way to invoke GUI taskbar (something which shows the current running processes) if exist in Ubuntu with some combination of keyword.

---

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to invoke terminal, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch from graphical desktop to virtual terminal. After logging in there, you will be able to enter commands.

You may try killing the `rdesktop` process from there (or investigating the problem any way you want). To return to `X`, and use graphical desktop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.